# Hecke operator on Jacobi forms

Tags: fourier-analysis, automorphic-forms

I study Jacobi forms and met the following problem: 
I need to prove that Hecke operator correclty defined
 
$U_d: J_{k, m} \to J_{k, md^2}$ - correctly defined map, $d \in \mathbb{N}$
 
$\phi(\tau, z) \mapsto \phi(\tau, dz)$ 
(so if we have [Jacobi form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_form) $\phi \in J_{k, m}$, then $U_d(\phi) \in J_{k, md^2}$) 
I want to prove it with fourier expansion of Jacobi form: 
$\phi(\tau, z) = \sum\limits_{n, l \in \mathbb{Z}}a(n, l) e^{2\pi i(n\tau + lz)}$. 
Since we deal with holomorphic Jacobi forms, we actually have the sum: (equivalent def of holomorphic Jacobi form)
$\phi(\tau, z) = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \sum\limits_{l^2 \leq 4mn} a(n, l) e^{2\pi in\tau}e^{2\pi i lz}$ 
But $U_d(\phi)(\tau, z) = \phi(\tau, dz) = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \sum\limits_{l^2 \leq 4mn} a(n, l) e^{2\pi in\tau}e^{d(2\pi i lz)}$ 
And since $4mn \leq 4mnd$, $U_d(\phi)$ "obviously" in $ J_{k, md^2}$. 
But my proof also imply that $U_d(\phi)$ in $J_{k, m}$, which is stronger conclusion. 
And I feel like somewhere I made a mistake, but cannot find it